# Clean way to trigger after_save callback when using sql to insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

In my create action on my controller, I am using a sql query to insert a parent record and all child records. But it doesn't trigger the after_save callback which I need. Is there a clean way of triggering this? I tried explicitly calling @record.save, but that slows down the submission of the form. Thanks

**Edit 1: Add relevant model/controller code**

**Model**

```
after_save { do_some_stuff }
```

**Controller**

```
def create
  insert_query = "SELECT fn_insert_order_all('#{param1}', '#{param2}', '#{param3}', #{param4});"
  new_record = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(insert_query)

  respond_to do |format|
    if new_record[0]["fn_insert_order_all"] != false
      @record = Order.find_by_id((new_record[0]["fn_insert_order_all"]).to_i)
      # @record.save # I can trigger the after_save callback here, but it results in slower performance
      format.json { render json: @record, status: :created }
    else
      error = { message: "record not saved" }
      format.json { render json: error, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant model and controller code.

Answer (score -1):

check in your model if you call after_create instead of after_save.

In the model the call to the triggered method should be something like:

```
after_create :your_func
```

In a model with a trigger I have working it looks like this:

```
class Mymodel < ActiveRecord::Base
    {attributes}
    after_create :your_func
        private
            def your_func
                {do the stuff}
            end
end
```

I hope that helps :)